# large SQL Performing quite slow (roughly 2 seconds for 290 rows) when having to deal with entries that can be NULL

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

```
SELECT version_stamp, 
           pscdesc_id, 
           psc, 
           pscdesctext 
    FROM   pscdesc_history 
    WHERE  ( psc IN (SELECT psc 
                     FROM   pso_history AS c 
                     WHERE  ( c.project = 121 
                               OR c.project IS NULL ) 
                     AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   pso_history AS x 
                                        WHERE  x.project = 121 
                                        AND x.pso_id = c.pso_id )) 
              OR psc IS NULL ) 
              AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   pscdesc_history AS xyy 
                       WHERE  xyy.psc IN (SELECT psc 
                                          FROM   pso_history AS c 
                                          WHERE  ( c.project = 121 
                                                   OR c.project IS NULL ) 
                                                 AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   pso_history AS x 
                                                             WHERE  x.project = 121 
                                                                    AND 
                                                            x.pso_id = c.pso_id)) 
                       AND xyy.pscdesc_id = pscdesc_history.pscdesc_id )
```

Maybe in prosa what I am trying to do:

Entries in the `pscdesc_history` table represent changes. Each entry is a change.

so a record with `pscdesc_id` can get changed, say `pscdesctext` gets changed. That gives us a new entry with the same `pscdesc_id` but a new `version_stamp` and `pscdesctext` the rest can be empty.
To which project these entries (crucial, since I only want to deal with one project) belong, I don't know. I have to look at the table `pso_history`. `psc` is the foreign key to a third table.

Why don't I just join? Since this is a table full of records of changes, the actual foreign key `psc` might be null. The same applies for `pso_history` where the forgein key `project` might be null too.

So i have to get all records of `pscdesc_history` that are related to a record in `pso_history` with a `pso_history.project` of 121 or that are related to a record with `pso_history.project` that was at some point 121.

Is there something you can see where you would think I could speed up things ? replace the `AND EXISTS` with something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DISTINCT everywhere you can and I don't understand why not to join instead of correlating

```
                 SELECT psc 
                 FROM   pso_history AS c 
                 WHERE  ( c.project = 121 
                           OR c.project IS NULL ) 
                 AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   pso_history AS x 
                                    WHERE  x.project = 121 
                                    AND x.pso_id = c.pso_id )


                 SELECT DISTINCT c.psc
                 FROM pso_history AS c
                 JOIN pso_history AS x 
                 ON      ( c.project = 121 OR c.project IS NULL )
                    AND   x.project = 121 
                    AND   x.pso_id = c.pso_id
```

And the entire query will be

```
SELECT  xyx.version_stamp, xyx.pscdesc_id, xyx.psc, xyx.pscdesctext 
FROM    pscdesc_history AS xyx
JOIN    pscdesc_history AS xyy
ON  (xyx.psc IN (SELECT DISTINCT c.psc
                 FROM pso_history AS c
                 JOIN pso_history AS X 
                 ON      ( c.project = 121 OR c.project IS NULL )
                    AND   x.project = 121 
                    AND   x.pso_id = c.pso_id) 
     OR xyx.psc IS NULL)
AND xyy.pscdesc_id = xyx.pscdesc_id
AND  xyy.psc IN ( SELECT DISTINCT c.psc
                 FROM pso_history AS c
                 JOIN pso_history AS X 
                 ON      ( c.project = 121 OR c.project IS NULL )
                    AND   x.project = 121 
                    AND   x.pso_id = c.pso_id)
```

This must work twice farster I think, check the indexes also.

Comment: what do you mean with correlating?

Comment: that seems like a nice query